# Safely closing thread reading socket inputstream from a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream

I have one thread that has a BufferedReader `in` reading from a socket's input stream. It runs in a while loop shown below. I also have a PrintWriter `out` that is in its own separate thread.

```
/*One thread*/
try {
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //do stuff
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/*Second thread*/
try {
    out.println("stuff");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

When a user requests to disconnect, which is being processed in a separate thread, I would like to safely close these threads that are reading from the stream.

When I try closing the `socket` (a static variable), I believe it should also close the input and output streams.

```
/*Third thread trying to stop the other threads so it can execute something*/
try {
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Thread1.join();
Thread2.join();
//Now do something else after the first two threads are done
```

However, my program is throwing a SocketException and points to `line = in.readLine())!=null`:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

It does disconnect, but how can I do it safely so that the SocketException isn't thrown? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: then catch it using the exeption that was thrown

Comment: I'm really wondering what is the proper way to close the input stream and socket such that there is no IOException/SocketException. I could just ignore it I suppose.

Comment: The code should be ready to deal with an IOException *anyway* so ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to close a socket that is blocked reading in another thread is to shut it down for input. That will deliver an EOS to the reading thread, which should cause it to close the socket and exit.

Comment: Cool, that works. Just for others, I called `socket.shutdownInput()` and `socket.shutdownOutput()` which should take the first thread out of the while loop. Then I called `join()` on the first two threads to make sure they finished. The socket automatically closes after that, so no need to do `socket.close()`

Comment: You don't need to call `shutdownOutput()`. That just tells the other end something that closing the socket will tell it anyway. You only need `shutdownInput(),` to unblock your reading thread. You must close either the socket's output stream or its input stream or the socket itself. Otherwise you have a socket leak.

Comment: In my program, I'm also allowing the user to reconnect, in which case I first check if the `!socket.isClosed()` and then call `socket.shutdownInput()` and `socket.shutdownOutput()`. When I remove `socket.shutdownOutput()` here, I get a socket exception when I call `socket.shutdownInput()` the second time (after connecting and disconnecting once). It says `Socket input is already shutdown.` If I don't call `socket.shutdownOutput()` when I disconnect, does it still look like the socket is open and tries to unsucessfully call `socket.shutdownInput()`?

Comment: @shimizu I don't understand the question. I don't understand why you would want to call `shutdownInput()` twice, or what it has to do with `shutdownOutput().` Shutdown for input and output are independent. You can call them both once each, and you must eventually close the socket.

Comment: I'm trying to use `shutdownInput()` on a socket that another thread is reading from with an ObjectInputStream. `shutdownInput()` does absolutely nothing unfortunately.